# Converting a TreeSet to ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, treeset

I have a TreeSet which contains > 100k objects.
I have another method which requires ArrayList as an param.

Is there any way I can accomplish this without iterating whole TreeSet and then adding each object manually to ArrayList ?

Comment: Is it possible to relax the method signature to receive a mere Collection?  That way no copying is needed.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

How about this:

```
new ArrayList<T>(set);
```

For Java 7 and later, this can be simplified, as type arguments `<T>` can be replaced with diamond type `<>`:

```
new ArrayList<>(set);
```

Comment: This is the best you're going to get.  There is no solution that doesn't require linear time.

Answer (score 5):

ArrayList has a convenience method `addAll` that fits the bill nicely:

```
final Set<Object> set = ...
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>(someBigNum);
list.addAll(set);
```

Comment: someBigNum could be set.size()

Comment: someBigNum is very misleading here... You don't need a big num. You just need set.size() as kuldeep pointed out

Answer (score 1):

In case one uses [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), which has super-powers and is developed by Goldman Sachs, there is `toList()`:

```java
MutableSortedSet<Object> set = SortedSets.mutable.empty();
...
return set.toList();
```

Providing a comparator is also possible:

```java
MutableSortedSet<Object> set = SortedSets.mutable.of(comparator);
...
return set.toList();
```