# Why last() and first() method is not present in Set Interface in java

Tags: java

I was trying to create a TreeSet instance using the below code.

```
Set<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
treeSet.last() //gives compilation error
//solution here is either to cast the treeSet instance  
//Or create treeSet using TreeSet concrete class. Which is not a best practice.
```

What to follow here ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: would this solve your problem ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322405/converting-a-treeset-to-arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set data structure behavior is not meant for ordering elements. So SET  dont have these methods. Treeset is middle way to achieve this functionality as it has ordering mechanism implemented with the fusion of

> Set + Red black Tree

data structure.

SortedSet is another implementation is been developed for this purpose.

Do it using

```
SortedSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
set.last();
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you require methods of the `SortedSet` interface, change the type of `treeSet` to `SortedSet`:

```
SortedSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
treeSet.last();
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Set interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) doesn't have those methods. Other data structures, like `HashSet`, implements the `Set` interface and they don't guarantee order so there is no use for those methods.

You can use the class instead of the interface

```
TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
```

Comment: I can add that `Set` is not designed for use `last()`, `first`:
`It models the mathematical set abstraction. The Set interface contains only methods inherited from Collection and adds the restriction that duplicate elements are prohibited.`
Collection itself doesn't provide those methods

Answer (score 0):

Set Interface does not have first() & last() methods, so use the TreeSet type

```
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        treeSet.last();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A set represents a collection that contains no duplicate elements. Thus the interface allows only the get set and iterate actions.

For your goal continue to use TreeSet (which implements the SortedSet)

```
TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `treeSet` is of type `Set` which doesn't have the `first` or `last` methods. If you will work with a TreeSet you will have access to those methods:

```
TreeSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
treeSet.last() //gives compilation error
//solution here is either to cast the treeSet instance  
//Or create treeSet using TreeSet concrete class. Which is not a best practice.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Set` interface is a collection that is not considered to be ordered. Although that's not explicit at the class level, it's all over the methods of the class, e.g. `iterator()`:

> Returns an iterator over the elements in this set. The elements are returned in no particular order (unless this set is an instance of some class that provides a guarantee).

In order to have a `first` and `last`, you need a order or an index, and Set has neither. As many other people have pointed out already, you can use `SortedSet` if you want an order.

`TreeSet` implements `SortedSet`, so you can certainly modify your supplied code to:

```
SortedSet<Integer> treeSet = new TreeSet<>();
treeSet.last();
```